# How can I tell if my C function is a computable function in computer science?

Tags: computer-science

**How can I tell if my C function is a computable function in computer science?**

I am trying to write C code that would be acceptable to computer scientists in the field of the theory of computation.

**It looks like anything that can be construed as a mapping from a tuple of natural numbers to a natural number is a computable function no matter what occurs in-between.**

We can assume that the function takes a finite string (or machine address of a finite string) input and derives a Boolean output. There is a dearth of material regarding the correspondence between C functions and computable functions.

I have been told that computable functions must be a pure function of their inputs. Several reviewers indicated that this may forbid the use of static local data.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993807/what-is-a-computable-function

Comment: In general, all C functions are computable unless they never return, as a CPU can obviously compute them. You typically need to exclude external events and memory-modifying interrupts, as these aren't covered by computability considerations. In addition, the semantics of a C function depends not only on the program code, but also on compiler and hardware behavior.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner That is great news. I have several reviewers that insist that any C function that uses static local data is not a computable function in computer science.  Perhaps they simply fibbed?

Comment: Perhaps you need a very precise definition of what a "computable function" is and read it very carefully. A "function" in mathematics maps input values to output values in a deterministic way. Without side effects.

Comment: @gnasher729 It looks like anything that can be construed as a mapping from a tuple of natural numbers to a natural number is a computable function not matter what occurs in-between. The problem is that several "reviewers" have indicated otherwise.

Comment: Static local data indeed makes a C function incompatible with the concept of computability unless you consider the static variables part of the input and output of the function.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner A C function H detects that its input P is a function that calls H in infinitely nested simulation only because it keeps track of the execution trace of P with static local data that is not erased between recursive simulations. This static local variable cannot be passed to H as a parameter because it would have to be passed through P.  If P passed NULL through in place of the execution trace then H would fail.

Comment: I don't see why you cannot arrange a version of H and P that both accept *and return* what otherwise would have been that static variable.  Sure, P doesn't use the value except to pass it on to H and back again, yet so?  Also has some similarities to monad, about capturing extra state not used/needed by all involved but passed around so it is there when it is desired.

Comment: @ErikEidt The P that I am referring to is the impossible input to the halting problem. All that is has to do is pass NULL along instead of the execution trace and it becomes the impossible input again.  I have a whole other approach if this one proves infeasible.

Comment: What on earth do you mean by "infinitely nested simulation" and "static local data that is not erased between recursive simulations"? The concept of "simulation" has nothing to do with C nor computable functions.

Comment: @Dai I have translated my very general question into the specific problem that I am trying to solve. softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/430016/… All of the theory of computation references to a computable function say that as long as you start with a the equivalent of a tuple of natural numbers and end up with the equivalent of a natural number that this function is computation no matter what happens in between. The final output is always the same for every initial input.

Comment: @polcott I think you misunderstand both the Halting problem and what "computable" means. I don't understand why you seem to think you're correct after everyone else in this thread, and your other post (both downvoted to oblivion) is disagreeing with you.

Comment: @Dai none of the many references to "computable functions" say that anything more is requires than an initial input tuple of natural numbers maps to a final output of a natural number.

Comment: @polcott As far as you're concerned, **C functions are not _mathematical functions_**, that's the point we're trying to get you to understand.

Comment: @Dai There is a unique mathematical mapping from an input finite string to a Boolean value entirely on the basis of a defined set of steps.

Comment: @polcott "There is a unique mathematical mapping from an input finite string to a Boolean value" - it's straightforward to demonstrate that the mathematical axioms you're referring do not apply in this case, so I can't tell if you're trolling or not...

Comment: @Dai I have spent thousands hours on this in the last two years. I created the x86utm operating system as my infrastructure. So far no one has been able to present this straight forward explanation. All that they provide is dogma.

Comment: @polcott If that's the case then I consider you a [crank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank_(person)) - and your `x86utm` operating-system doesn't prove anything and was ripped-apart in this thread: https://groups.google.com/g/comp.ai.philosophy/c/prpn3AcCB1U - In all sincerity, I think you should see a qualified mental-health professional: delusional behavior can indicate more serious underlying neurological issues.

Comment: @Dai so what is the straight forward explanation?

Comment: @polcott The straightforward explanation [is that you probably have a delusional disorder](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/diseases/9599-delusional-disorder), frankly. (This is not an ad-hom attack, I'm basing this off your post history both on SO and that Google thread).

Comment: @Dai many people have critiqued my work and on that basis I have addressed their objections. I cannot address an unspecified objection. It just doesn't make sense to be that C can do something that is not TM computable.

Comment: This is not a discussion board, and the question isn't leading anywhere, so I'm casting a close vote. Nothing personal.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner: I think this is an answerable question - it is surely based on a misunderstanding, but that's exactly what my answer is about. I would liek to encourage you to rethink your close vote after reading my answer.

Comment: @Dai: *"C functions are not mathematical functions,"* - yes, I agree, absolutely, I took this as a basis for an answer, no need to argue with the OP here in the comments.

Comment: "It looks like anything that can be construed as a mapping from a tuple of natural numbers to a natural number is a computable function no matter what occurs in-between." – This is not true. For example, the function `H(p, i)` which returns `1` if program `p` (represented as a natural number) with input `i` (represented as a natural number) halts in a finite number of steps, `0` otherwise is a simple mapping of a tuple of natural numbers to natural numbers, but is the most famous non-computable function.

Comment: @JörgWMittag on the other hand here is that same function that <is> computed: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/351947980_Halting_problem_undecidability_and_infinitely_nested_simulation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formal definition for "computable functions" is given behind the two links you already posted in the question, and they are better than anything I could repost here again, but let me try to explain some things here:

- A computable function *f* is a **mathematical function**  f: A->B, where its mapping from the set A to B can be effectively computed by some **model of computation**. Note that A and B have to be finite or infinite countable set (often it is assumed A = **N**^k, B = **N** , **N** =set of natural numbers).
- A function in a programming language like C is *not* a mathematical function, it is a **language construct** which was modeled in **analogy** to mathematical functions. To make the difference more apparent, one could use the language-agnostic term [subroutine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subroutine) for them (though in C, "function" is definitely the more common name). C functions operate on strings and/or finite numbers, they can also take pointers to other functions as input, and they can have "side effects" as well as become influenced by side effects.

Hence it is easy to mix up these two concepts since both use the same term "function" for different things. It also shows that when reading your question literally, a "C function" is *never* a computable function, since it is not even a function  - in the strictly mathematical sense.

**But what is the relationship between "C functions" and "computable functions"?**

Well, if we use the C programming language as our "model of computation", we could say that in a less rigourous sense, a mathematical function `f:A->B` is computable when there is a corresponding C function F which is a "sufficiently good approximation" for f. What does that mean?

My understanding about this is the following: for ease of explanation let us take A to be the set of finite character strings and B={0,1}. Then we would expect f(x) = F(x) for all values in x from A, assumed our C function would run on an idealized machine with no restrictions on memory and string lengths. Note this definition can be expanded to arbitrary countable sets A and B which map to tuples of data types in the language C.

**So if C functions are our model of computation, would that not make any C function "computable" by definition?**

No. To my understanding, it makes only sense to apply the term "computable" to a C function F when there is a mathematical function f where F can be used to proof its computability. For this, only a certain class of C functions are suitable, they need to fulfill the following conditions:

1. F must be guaranteed to return a value, it must not run in an infinite loop or exit program
2. F must not be influenced by any side-effects (since it would make it impossible to guarantee F(x)=f(x) for all x). Note that F having any side-effects itself, however, does not necessarily preclude this, but side-effects could be also seen as a "disturbing additional return value", hence it is generally better to exclude C functions of this type as well.

There is a well-known name for this kind of programming language functions in computer science: they are called [**pure functions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), to cite Wikipedia:

> a pure function is a computational analogue of a mathematical function

Note from condition 1, it follows that a "computable C function" (or pure function) F must not take another C function as input (or at least: must not call such another function passed as parameter), since it cannot be guaranteed that a call to that other function would ever return. Condition 2 forbids, for example the usage of statics (neither locally or globally), since it could influence the output of the computation.

Hope this helps to bring some light into it.

Comment: "A and B have to be infinite countable set" Thus a TM that picks out the even numbers from the subset of natural numbers from 1 to 100 is not a computation. Your wording needs improvement.

Comment: Another answer is a different group seemed to indicate that only the first element of pure function is required for C code to be a computable function.

Comment: "The function return values are identical for identical arguments (no variation with local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference arguments or input streams)." This seems to say that as long as "the function return values are identical for identical arguments" all of the other items on this list don't make any difference because there is {no variation} with any of them.

Comment: @polcott: 1. see my edit. 2. I have no idea what you mean by "first element". 3. what do you mean by "this list"?

Comment: ... and if you are unsure whether a certain C function is pure, you may ask a new question on this site where you post the function's code and explain why the Wikipedia article about pure functions did not help you to answer your question. Also, I would recommend to stop using the term "computable" for programming language functions, that's the term to be used for mathematical functions.

Comment: {I have no idea what you mean by "first element"} The first of the two numbered items on this list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function It may be the case that the first item on this list is a good criteria for computable function.  Another answer to a similar question seems to indicate that the second numbered item can be ignored as long as the first numbered item is met.

Comment: @polcott: well, I wrote the same  in my answer.  There is no broad consensus of what a  "computable C function" should be in CS, so *you* need to define it by yourself. If you stick to pure functions, or if you use "almost" pure functions (with side effects, but not being influenced by them) is completely up to you.  But when your goal is to communicate with other computer scientists, it will be simpler when you stick to their accepted terms. Say "pure function" if you mean that, and "almost pure function, except that is has side effects" if you mean that.

Comment: ... and don't invent new terms if you don't need to - as I explained in my answer, a "computable C function" would be your own invention.

Comment: I created the x86utm operating system so that theory of computation problems could be examined at the high level abstraction of the C programming language. To check my understanding of what you said I will paraphrase it: If a C function is a pure function then everyone will understand that it is TM computable. If a C function is "a pure function of its inputs" (list item 1) then some will understand that it it TM computable and others will not.  Is the above paraphrase accurate?

Comment: It turns out that I can transform my code into a pure function so your answer was the key for me to finish this project. I asked a similar question in another forum, yet needed to be certain of the correct answer. As long as my code is a "pure function" then it seems to meet the spec of TM computable.

Comment: Can't A and B be uncountable sets in a sufficiently powerful model of computation?

Comment: @user253751: I don't know, sounds like a valid question for https://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I count that as my final long sought after answer. It was only this year that I understood he Church-Turing thesis to only apply to computable functions. This is far far more limited that I ever imagined.